# English language and Mathematics

Tags: smooth-manifolds, terminology, hypersurfaces, transversality, integration

I have a question maybe more relevant to an English language section of StackExchange, but I doubt that anybody but a Mathematician could properly answer my question.

Let $\mathcal M$ be a smooth manifold, let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $\mathcal M$ and let $\Sigma$ be a smooth hypersurface of $\mathcal M$. Let $t\mapsto \gamma(t,x)$ be the integral curve of $X$ originating at $x\in \Sigma$.
The vector field $X$ is tranverse to $\Sigma$ at $x\in \Sigma$ whenever
$\dot \gamma(0,x)\notin T_x(\Sigma)$: we may say as well in that case that the curve $\gamma$ is transverse to $\Sigma$.

When $\gamma$ is not transverse to $\Sigma$, I suppose that for some $k\ge 2$ 
$$
\frac{d^l\gamma}{dt^l}(0,x)\in T_x(\Sigma)\quad\text{for $1\le l\le k-1$}, \quad
\frac{d^k\gamma}{dt^k}(0,x)\notin T_x(\Sigma),
$$
and I want to say that [the order of contact of $\gamma$ with $\Sigma$ is exactly $k$]
or that [the curve $\gamma$ is tangential to $\Sigma$ with a contact of order $k$]. Are these formulations correct?

Comment: I like "the curve gamma is tangent to Sigma with a contact of order k"

Comment: I like the first one. It seems pretty standard: for example the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(mathematics) uses more or less this formulation.

Comment: Both of your examples sound like idiomatic mathematical English to me.  Possibly other ways of saying it are more established in the literature, but the fact that you are asking this question puts an upper bound on just how well established these hypothetical other ways are.

Comment: I would be more concerned about specifying whether this counts as order $k$ or order $k-1$.

Comment: Sigma has a tangential curve gamma with an order of contact k

Comment: @Neil Strickland The function $t\mapsto t^2$ is vanishing at order 2 at $0$, no other order of vanishing is relevant.